# How to manipulate form data before sending to server?

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I want to collect 25 schedule times (hour and minutes). User will input 25 times using drop down boxes. That means, 25 hour and 25 minutes drop down boxes, making total 50 drop down boxes. But I don't need to send them as individual variables. One string like- `08:05;08:37;09:43;09:59:11:12;12:34` will do.

So, the variable to send will be like- `time=08:05;08:37;09:43;09:59:11:12;12:34`

I think it will be easy - user presses submit button, all the variables from 50 drop down boxes will make a string and then send that string.

How to do that? any ideas? any suggestion?

Any example or tutorial on this is appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - add onSubmit even to the form. Using javascript generate the string and set it to the hidden variable. This can get ugly without JS Framework like jquery or mootools.

Option 2 - use array structure. submit form as normal and parse arrays using php script.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<select name="data[1][hour]">...</select><select name="data[1][minute]">...</select>
<select name="data[2][hour]">...</select><select name="data[2][minute]">...</select>
...
...
<select name="data[25][hour]">...</select><select name="data[25][minute]">...</select>


<?php
// PHP
$data = array();
for ($i=1;$i<=25;$i++){
   $data[] = $_POST['data'][$i]['hour'].':'$_POST['data'][$i]['minute']
}
$dataString = implode(';', $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) & [jquery.calendrical](http://tobiascohen.com/demos/calendrical/):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>S.O. 3664773</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://tobiascohen.com/demos/calendrical/jquery.calendrical.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tobiascohen.com/demos/calendrical/calendrical.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var gEnd = 25;

    // borrowed from jquery.calendrical sources
    function parseTime(text) {
        var match = match = /(\d+)\s*[:\-\.,]\s*(\d+)\s*(am|pm)?/i.exec(text);
        if (match && match.length >= 3) {
            var hour = Number(match[1]);
            var minute = Number(match[2])
            if (hour == 12 && match[3]) hour -= 12;
            if (match[3] && match[3].toLowerCase() == 'pm') hour += 12;
            if (hour < 10) hour = '0' + hour;
            if (minute < 10) minute = '0' + minute;
            return {
                hour:   hour,
                minute: minute
            };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#time').calendricalTime();
        $('#submit-btn').val('End (' + gEnd + ')');

        $('#add').click(function() {
            var hm = parseTime($('#time').val());
            var li = $('<li></li>').text(
                hm.hour + ":" + 
                hm.minute);
            $('#input').append(li);
            --gEnd;
            $('#submit-btn').val('End (' + gEnd + ')');
        });

        $('#addForm').submit(function() {
            var ul = "";

            $('#input li').each(function() {
                ul += $(this).html() + ";"
            });

            alert("About to submit: time=" + ul.replace(/;$/, '')); 
            return false; // don't submit
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<ol id="input">
</ol>
<form id="addForm">
    <input id="time" type="text" /> 
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="End"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example using jQuery. You'll find in the example an option to submit a "hidden" form with a unique hidden field. That allows you to send your data in a POST variable without the 50 others variables from the `SELECT` fields

```
<!-- your form with your 50 select fields -->
<form id="myform">
<select id="hour1" ...></select>
<select id="min1" ...></select>
<select id="hour2" ...></select>
<select id="min2" ...></select>
...
<select id="hour25" ...></select>
<select id="min25" ...></select>
</form>

<!-- if you want to "simulate" the submission of a form without 
your 50 select fields you'll need to include this form and hide it in css -->
<form id="myform2" action="..." method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="myvars" value="" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){

    // on submit of the #myform form
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        // create the unique variable: myvars
        var myvars = 'time=';
        for(var i=1; i<=25; i++) {
            myvars += $('#hour'+i).val() + ':' + $('#min'+i).val() + ';';
        }
        // if you want to get rid of the last ";" you can add:
        myvars = myvars.replace(/^;$/, '');

        // you can do whatever you want with "myvars" here
        // or make a submission with the hidden form to "simulate"
        // the submission of a form with the data in
        // a POST variable

        $('#myform2 input[name=myvars]').val(myvars);
        $('#myform2').trigger('submit');

        return false; // to cancel the "normal" submit
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use date.getTime() which returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object. That is a long value. You can use that separated by ',' or '|' (or any other arbitrary character for that matter). On your server you can initiate a your times based off that long value again.
Hope it helps!